# Assigning value to integer literal

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

> Whenever a prvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a glvalue for that operand, the [temporary materialization conversion](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval) is applied to convert the expression to an xvalue.
>
> <sub>Source: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#7</sub>

Why is `5 = 6` ill-formed? Should it not perform a temporary materialization conversion, and create an assignable temporary?

Comment: A integer literal is an unnamed constant.  Constants can only be rvalues, and unnamed values can only be rvalues.  So 5 is not a suitable lvelue.  It cannot be converted to an lvalue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`5 = 6` is illegal by fiat. That is, it's illegal because [[expr.ass]/1 explicitly says so](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.ass#1):

> All [assignment operators] require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand

5 is not a modifiable lvalue. Therefore, this rule is violated and the code is il-formed. Note that it doesn't expect a "glvalue" generally; it requires a "modifiable lvalue" *specifically*.